# jQuery - Slider with Fadein Effect

Tags: jquery, fadein

In this code

**HTML**

```
<div class="switch-content">
  <a href="#" id="content-1">link1</a>
  <a href="#" id="content-2">link2</a>
  <a href="#" id="content-3">link3</a>
</div>

<div class="show-content-1">Content 1</div>
<div class="show-content-2 hidden">Content 2</div>
<div class="show-content-3 hidden">Content 3</div>
```

**jQuery**

```
$('.switch-content a').on("click", function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  var $this = $(this),
      $id = $this.attr('id'),
      $class = '.' + $('.show-' + $id).attr('class').replace('hidden', '');

  $('.show-' + $id).removeClass('hidden');
  $('div[class*=show]').not($class).addClass('hidden');
});
```

**CSS**

```
.hidden {display: none;}
```

http://codepen.io/mehmet/pen/HqlAn

How can I make it so the content fades in, instead of just nested show up when the link is clicked?

Comment: http://api.jquery.com/fadein/ , enjoy.

Comment: I know that one, but I wasn't able to implement it to my code thats why I asked help Shaeldon. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change your code to this for a fade transition :) http://codepen.io/anon/pen/qjIxL

```
$('.switch-content a').on("click", function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  var $this = $(this),
      $id = $this.attr('id'),
      $class = '.' + $('.show-' + $id).attr('class').replace('hidden', '');


  $('div[class*=show]').not($class).fadeOut().promise().done( function(){
    $('.show-' + $id).fadeIn();
  });
});
```

Comment: You deserve better reputation

Comment: Thank you very much Bojan, I really appreciate it.